# Cannot get Moto G to output over SlimPort adapter

Tags: hdmi, motorola-moto-g, slimport

I am having a problem getting a display to my Panasonic TV from my Moto G when I connect it using a SlimPort adapter. I connected the HDMI cable to the HDMI 2 port. I connected the phone to the SlimPort adapter and the adapter to the HDMI cable. I changed to HDMI 2 on the TV. Nothing displays. Is this because my Moto G phone has limited capabilities, or what could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

SlimPort is not supported on the Moto G ([nor is MHL](https://forums.motorola.com/posts/8fba3591e7)). You can find a list of compatible devices on the [SlimPort website](http://us.slimportconnect.com/slimport-supported-devices/).